# why matplotlib give the error [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0392A9D0>]?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python 2.7.9 on win8. When I tried to plot using matplotlib, the following error showed up:

> from pylab import *
>   plot([1,2,3,4])
>
> **[matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0392A9D0]**

I tried the test code "python simple_plot.py --verbose-helpful", and the following warning showed up:

> $HOME=C:\Users\XX
>   matplotlib data path C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data
>
> ---
>
> You have the following UNSUPPORTED LaTeX preamble customizations:
>
> Please do not ask for support with these customizations active.
>
> ---
>
> loaded rc file C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc
>   matplotlib version 1.4.3
>   verbose.level helpful
>   interactive is False
>   platform is win32
>   CACHEDIR=C:\Users\XX.matplotlib
>   Using fontManager instance from C:\Users\XX.matplotlib\fontList.cache
>   backend TkAgg version 8.5
>   findfont: Matching :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=medium to Bitstream
>   Vera Sans (u'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\Vera.ttf') with score of 0.000000

What does this mean? How could I get matplotlib working?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That isn't an error.  That has created a plot object but you need to show the window.  That's done using [`pyplot.show()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show).
As stated in the comments, please do not use `pylab`, but use `matplotlib.pyplot` instead as `pylab` has been deprecated.  As such, all you have to do is call:

```
plt.show()
```

Just for reproducibility, here's a trace from the Python REPL (using IPython):

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x123245290>]

In [3]: plt.show()
```

We get:

[image]

---

## What about in a Jupyter notebook?

If you are using this in a Jupyter notebook, instead of having to use `show()`, you can place the following in a separate cell after you import `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

This will automatically draw the figure once you create it and you will not have to use `show()` after you're done.

Comment: you should not use `pylab`, the recommended method is now `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` `plt.plot(...)`

Comment: @tcaswell - I'm copying the OP's code.  That is obviously what I recommend to.  I'm editing my post actually to mention this.

Comment: @tcaswell - Edited.  Thanks for the spot... and thanks for `matplotlib` :)

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you! I did the thing you recommended, and it worked! But I still have the following problem. When I saved the following code as a .py file in notepad++ and then ran it in powershell, an error popped up. But if I typed the code in powershell one line by line, it worked. Why is that?                                                                             >import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()                                                                              >C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'plot': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @susansecret - Python is a whitespace delimited language.  Did you make sure that there is no leading or trailing white space for each line of code? Also, make sure that each line of code is on a separate line... and it's not all on a single line! :)

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I put them in different lines. Since I just started using stackoverflow, I am still learning how to comment here...

Comment: @susansecret no worries.  How are you calling the code in PowerShell?  Are you doing `python file.py` where `file.py` is the name of your file?  BTW, once we're done here, I'd love it if you could accept my answer :)

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I called "python file.py" in powershell. (Thank you for reminding me to accept your answer. As I said, I am still learning..)

Comment: @susansecret - Oh that's fine.  Thank you.  Hmm... interesting.  Without using `matplotlib.pyplot`, did it work in your script??

Comment: @rayryeng Do you mean by running just "plot([1,2,3,4])
show()"? If so, the same error message showed up. What does this mean?

Comment: In [jupyter lab](https://jupyter.org/), which is the current version of jupyter notebook, `%matplotlib inline` is not required. Also, that edit is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021612/7758804)

Answer (score 3):

In Jupyter nodebook, you could just insert

```
%matplotlib inline
```

before you use `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `plt.plot()` on Spider, you will now receive the following notification:

> Figures now render in the Plots pane by default. To make them also appear inline in the Console, uncheck "Mute Inline Plotting" under the Plots pane options menu.

I followed this instruction, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

These are good answers but I suspect many people will come here because they are in Google colab and they copied a Jupyter notebook from someone else that has

```
 %matplotlib
```

somewhere in it. Just delete it.

(or as noted in other answers, add the inline)

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem. You just have to use `show()` function to show it in a window. Use `pyplot.show()`